# How to call return value from stored procedure in Entity Framework Core in POST method?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core 3.1. This is the snippets of my stored procedure, I am not allowed to make any changes to it. Basically just pass the parameters into the SP using EF Core and display the return value.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOG_DELIVERY_ORDER]
    @Company varchar(50),
    @Company_Name varchar(50),
    @Customer_Code varchar(50),
    @Customer_Name varchar(50),
    @Customer_Address varchar(max),
    @DO_No varchar(50),
    @Invoice_No varchar(50),
    @Account_No varchar(50),
    @Van_Code varchar(50),
    @Salesperson varchar(50),
    @Total_Quantity_Loaded int,
    @Date_Created datetime,
    @Created_By int,
    @Location_Created varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    (the rest) 

    IF @@ERROR=0
        SELECT @@IDENTITY AS result
    ELSE
        SELECT 0
END
```

And this is the expected return after execution:

[Output of the stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsDUX.png)

The stored procedure will return the latest ID made in 'result' column after the parameters being inserted.

My model:

```
public partial class LogDeliveryOrder
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
    public string DoNo { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceNo { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    public string VanCode { get; set; }
    public string Salesperson { get; set; }
    public int TotalQuantityLoaded { get; set; }
    public string DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string LocationCreated { get; set; }
    public string LocationModified { get; set; }

    public int result { get; set; }
}
```

My entities:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<LogDeliveryOrder>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();
            entity.Property(e => e.AccountNo);
            entity.Property(e => e.CompanyName);
            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedBy);
            entity.Property(e => e.CustomerAddress);
            entity.Property(e => e.CustomerCode);
            entity.Property(e => e.CustomerName);
            entity.Property(e => e.DateCreated);
            entity.Property(e => e.DoNo);
            entity.Property(e => e.InvoiceNo);
            entity.Property(e => e.LocationCreated);
            entity.Property(e => e.LocationModified);
            entity.Property(e => e.Salesperson);
            entity.Property(e => e.TotalQuantityLoaded);
            entity.Property(e => e.VanCode);

            entity.Property(e => e.result);
        });
```

POST method:

```
[HttpPost("LogDeliveryOrder")]
public IActionResult LogDeliveryOrder([FromBody] LogDeliveryOrder deliveryOrder) 
{
        using (LogDeliveryContext context = new LogDeliveryContext())
        {
            string sql = $"exec [dbo].[KLCONNECT_LOG_DELIVERY_ORDER_INS_210501] " +
                        $"@Company = '{deliveryOrder.CompanyName}', " +
                        $"@Company_Name = '{deliveryOrder.CompanyName}', " +
                        $"@Customer_Code = '{deliveryOrder.CustomerCode}', " +
                        $"@Customer_Name = '{deliveryOrder.CustomerName}', " +
                        $"@Customer_Address = '{deliveryOrder.CustomerAddress}', " +
                        $"@DO_No = '{deliveryOrder.DoNo}', " +
                        $"@Invoice_No = '{deliveryOrder.InvoiceNo}', " +
                        $"@Account_No = '{deliveryOrder.AccountNo}', " +
                        $"@Van_Code = '{deliveryOrder.VanCode}', " +
                        $"@Salesperson = '{deliveryOrder.Salesperson}', " +
                        $"@Total_Quantity_Loaded = {deliveryOrder.TotalQuantityLoaded}, " +
                        $"@Date_Created = '{deliveryOrder.DateCreated}', " +
                        $"@Created_By = {deliveryOrder.CreatedBy}, " +
                        $"@Location_Created = '{deliveryOrder.LocationCreated}' ";
            
            var storedProcedure = context.LogDeliveryOrders.FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList();
         
            return Ok(storedProcedure);
        }
}
```

But when I try to insert the parameters into the stored procedure, it throws this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The required column 'AccountNo' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.'

However I do not expect `AccountNo` in the result. I only expect column 'result' in return. The stored procedure however successfully executed. The parameters did inserted to the table. However I still not able to retrieve the 'result' column and the ID. I already made the class and entity for 'result'. How do I retrieve it?

Comment: Use the result class in your FromSql call.

Comment: How to use the class? you mean "var storedProcedure = context.Resultclass.FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList(); " like this?? i'm newbie in ef core. thanks for helping in advance

Comment: Yes, exactly like that!